# Configure Xampp for TYPO3

Tags: windows, xampp, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have to learn how to use TYPO3 for an end-of-study internship. I use the last version of TYPO3.
And I want to use the local server Xampp on Windows 10. But I never used it before and I don't know how to configure it for TYPO3. I try to use the documentation on TYPO3's website but I don't really understand.
Could you help me ?

[image]

Comment: have you tried MAMP PRO for windows? I found the config quite straightforward

Comment: I can't. I don't have money to buy MAMP PRO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first three messages can be resolved by changing the entries in the „php.ini“ file with an editor. 
1);extension=php_soap.dll will be activated by removing the semicolon
2) max_execution_time = 30 has to be increased to 240
3) ; max_input_vars = 1000 will be activated by removing the semicolon and has to be increased to 1500 characters

Now restart Apache and MySQL with the XAMPP Control Panel and reload the website.

The „ThreadStackSize“ has to be raised to 8MB. In order to change this setup write the following lines with a text editor in the file „httpd.conf“:

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadStackSize 8388608
</ IfModule>
```

The last error „PHP OpenSSL extension not working“ can be ignored, since it’s just a local test system. So security is not that important in this case.

This information and more you can find here: https://www.pagemachine.de/blog/install-typo3-8-0-local-test-system-windows-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks ! It works but I have an error in the xampp console when I edit "httpd.conf".
08:22:35  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
08:22:35  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
08:22:35  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
08:22:35  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
08:22:35  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
08:22:35  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
08:22:35  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

Comment: An Alternative is to use the Bitnami TYPO3 installation.

Comment: Thanks ! It works but I can not to typo3 and acces the back-end of Typo3. I try to use http://127.0.0.1/typo3/admin or http://127.0.0.1/typo3/login to acces to the connection module but I don't work.
Sorry to bother you with my stupid problem.

Comment: Please try: localhost/name-of-folder-with-your-typo3-installation/typo3/

Comment: I try but I have this : casimages.com/i/161203044336158961.png.html Typo3 is the link for typo3 official website 
Manage is for the index file of bitnami.

Comment: Okay, it's Bitnami. Idon't have a Bitnami installation so I guess you have to write localhost/typo3/typo3/